# How to sort aggrupations using Excel/Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, sorting, grouping

I'm facing the next problem: I have in Excel the following database and I want to sort the 'Amount' variable ascendently taking into account there are 3 different groups (GROUP X, ITEM ZZ AND GROUP Z) and not only the groups have to be sorted but their correponding items too.

- GROUP X has 3 different items to be sorted ascendently (ITEM XA, ITEM XB, ITEM XC).
- ITEM ZZ is an item with no group, so it can be considered as a group by itself.
- GROUP Y has 4 items (ITEM YA, ITEM YB, ITEM YC, ITEM YD) to be sorted ascendently.

The database I'm working with is the next one:

| Code | Name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10010 | GROUP X | 20000 |
| 10011 | ITEM XA | 2000 |
| 10012 | ITEM XB | 8000 |
| 10013 | ITEM XC | 10000 |
| 10020 | ITEM ZZ | 22000 |
| 10030 | GROUP Y | 26000 |
| 10031 | ITEM YA | 11000 |
| 10032 | ITEM YB | 5000 |
| 10033 | ITEM YC | 9000 |
| 10043 | ITEM YD | 1000 |

Ant the result I want to get after sorting the variables is the following one:

| Code | Name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10030 | GROUP Y | 26000 |
| 10031 | ITEM YA | 11000 |
| 10033 | ITEM YC | 9000 |
| 10032 | ITEM YB | 5000 |
| 10043 | ITEM YD | 1000 |
| 10020 | ITEM ZZ | 22000 |
| 10010 | GROUP X | 20000 |
| 10013 | ITEM XC | 10000 |
| 10012 | ITEM XB | 8000 |
| 10011 | ITEM XA | 2000 |

As you can see, it has first the groups sorted and inside each group the items are sorted ascendetly as well.

If anyone could help me solving this problem I'd be very grateful

Comment: Because you are following a non logical sorting (logical would be a-z, z-a), you'll need a helper column for this, so depending on value of `Name` you can assign a value and order by that. Also, you tagged the question with VBA and VB.NET, which are **not** the same. IF you want an VBA solution, post the code you've tried.

Comment: Thanks in advance for your answer. There's already an auxiliar column named 'Code' for which the first 4 values are the same for its corresponding groups and items. However, it's not enough to get the wished result. Besides, the other tags in the questions are just because Excel might not be able to solve this problems so I'm open to try in other different ways.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in Excel alone.

To obtain the results you show, you need to sort by:

- `Group` in the custom order of `Y,Z,X`
- and then by Amount in descending order

Group is the first letter of the last word of the Name

Create a custom column with the formula:

```
=LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)))
```

Then enter the sort dialog:

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Comment: I knew about custom lists, but had no idea they could be used as custom sort field. This is so good. I was thinking in a helper column with numerical values depending on group, but this answer is, indeed, best option.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns That is actually the main use I have for custom lists in Excel :-)